# Как сделать точную паузу?

Tags: c++, winapi

По моим наблюдениям оказалось что функция `Sleep()` из windows.h выполняется нисколько не то количество времени которое мы указали.Более того,например `Sleep(10)` в windows 7 будет выполняться не столько же времени как в windows 10.Почему так может происходить и есть ли функции которые будут делать точную паузу во всех операционках,либо способы?

P.s Как я посчитал,то `Sleep` или `sleep_for` выполняются по 1 миллисекунде,если записать 10 штук подряд по 10 милисек и посчитать их время ,получается 110мс

P.s.s Если записать 10 подряд идущих `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` и указать им время меньше 1 миллисекунды,т е в наносекундах,то время выполнения этих 10 слипов будет 20 миллисекунд,что вообще происходит?

Comment: Ну почему же "нисколько не то"? Достаточно близко. Или вы хотели написать "несколько не то"?...

Comment: Вы правы. В популярных ОС нет функций, которые  гарантируют точное ожидание. Реально, вся работа со временем в них (даже внутри ядра) достаточно приблизительна. Более того, популярные аппаратные средства также не могут точно измерять время.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В вашей операционной системе (ОС) одновременно выполняется куча различных программ, но вот процессор у вас только один и обработать за раз он может ограниченное количество задач. Поэтому в ОС предусмотренны [потоки выполнения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) и ОС постоянно переключается между ними, выдавая каждому определенное процессорное время.

[Команда Sleep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) говорит о том, что процесс будет ждать определенное кол-во системного времени и продолжит выполняться только тогда, когда оно пройдет и ОС выдаст ему право продолжить выполнение. Вот тут вы и сталкиваетесь с разницей, поскольку уходит время на переключение потоков и решения ОС по поводу того, какому из них дать приоритет.

Способов заставить ОС выполнять задачу ровно указанное кол-во времени мне не известно. В книге "Windows для профессионалов" у Рихтера, который является авторитетом в мире программирования под Windows, есть такая цитата:

> Меня часто спрашивают, как сделать так, чтобы поток гарантированно
>   запускался в течение определенного времени после какого-нибудь события
>   — например, не позднее чем через миллисекунду после приема данных с
>   последовательного порта? Ответ прост: никак. Такие требования можно
>   предъявлять к операционным системам реального времени, но Windows к
>   ним не относится. Лишь операционная система реального времени имеет
>   полное представление о характеристиках аппаратных средств, на которых
>   она работает (об интервалах запаздывания контроллеров жестких дисков,
>   клавиатуры и т.д.). А создавая Windows, Microsoft ставила другую цель
>   обеспечить поддержку максимально широкого спектра оборудования —
>   различных процессоров, дисковых устройств, сетей и др. Короче говоря,
>   Windows не является операционной системой реального времени.
>
> Вызывая Sleep, поток добровольно отказывается от остатка выделенного
>   ему кванта времени.  Система прекращает выделять потоку процессорное
>   время на период, примерно равный заданному. Все верно: если Вы укажете
>   остановить поток на 100 мс, приблизительно на столько он и "заснет",
>   хотя не исключено, что его сон продлится на несколько секунд или даже
>   минут больше. Windows не является системой реального
>   времени. Ваш поток может возобновиться в заданный момент, но это
>   зависит от того, какая ситуация сложится в системе к тому времени.

Comment: а смысл тогда в  std::this_thread::sleep_for()?Ведь в нем мы можем задать количество времени в  наносекундах.И что мне лучше делать чтоб "приостановка" программы была максимально точна

Comment: @Whitehorse, смысл в том, что там указывается _минимум_, а не максимум. То есть, гарантируется что поток проснётся _не раньше_, чем истечёт указанное время.